# ViewChild not working after upgrading to angular 9

Tags: angular

Does anything change in ViewChild? After upgrade to Angular 9 MatSideNav menu stopped working.

```
export class SidenavOpenCloseExample implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('menuSide', {read: MatSidenav, static: true}) menuSide: MatSidenav;

   opened: boolean;

   ngOnInit(): void {
       console.log("OnInit: " + this.menuSide);
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log("AfterViewInit: " + this.menuSide);
   }

   toggle() {
      this.menuSide.close();
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
   <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
     Sidenav content
   </mat-sidenav>

   <mat-sidenav-content>
      <p><button mat-button (click)="toggle()">Toggle menu</button></p>
   </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I created sample with this behaviour
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfkaha?file=src/app/sidenav-open-close-example.ts)

Comment: You're using `menuSide` in the `ViewChild` when you should be using `sidenav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No i don't think they change anything on ViewChilds, but i think you made a typo, it should be:

```
@ViewChild('sidenav', {read: MatSidenav, static: true}) menuSide: MatSidenav;
```

an not:

```
@ViewChild('menuSide', {read: MatSidenav, static: true}) menuSide: MatSidenav;
```

Since you have no `#menuSide` in your component html.

Comment: hmm, you are right, that's copy paste error, but on my original project I don't have that mistake, but if example works I may got an error somewhere else, thanks

Comment: Ok so my problem was related to this bit *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async". I put it into MatSideNav and because logging is happening after menu loads it was never assigning menuSide to my variable. Thanks for your help